# How to link a spinner with a switch in Android

Tags: java, android

I am wondering how i would go about creating a butting which will save data to a txt file on the local android device based on what is selected in a spinner and also the position of a switch.

I can already save to the txt file so that part im ok with. What i am having issues is the best approach for saving based on the above.

so for eg,

if the spinner is selected with bananas from its list and the switch is on, i am wanting the on click to recognize this and write it back to the txt file.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to know how to check when the button is on and something from the spinner is selected or something else?

Comment: switch. setOnCheckedChangeListener(...)
spinner. setOnItemSelectedListener(...)

? Dunno what else you´re asking for

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I made something previously in App inventor and i've been trying to convert to Android studio and learn at the same time. So i have a spinner with 4 items, banana, apple, pear, melon. i then have a switch which has on and off. finally a save button.
What i am trying to recreate is that when i click the Save button, it will save whatever is selected in the spinner and also the position of the switch. The output will then read in the txt file - banana&on or apple&off.